# Extend a line path without changing the angle in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

How do I drag the end of an angled line path to extend it without changing the angle of the entire line path itself? I have multiple parallel paths I need to extend but do not want to change any angles

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to Illustrator> Preferences>Smart Guides and check the box Anchor/ Path Labels

Select one end of the line with the Direct Selection Tool (White Arrow) and the Smart Guide highlight will read **Line Extension** when you are extending the line at the same original angle.

[image]

Comment: Is this pixel perfect? I’ve struggled with getting smart guides to work like I feel they should.

Answer (score 0):

The are multiple ways to achieve this, all of them basically scale the object proportionally. It pays for all of them to untick 'Scale Strokes and Effects' in the Preferences.

### Scale tool

1. Select the object
2. Double-click on the Scale Tool icon in the Toolbox
3. Enter a percentage over 100% in the 'uniform' box and click OK.

### Free Transform tool

1. Select the object
2. Activate the Free Transform tool <kbd>E</kbd>
3. Start dragging on one of the corner anchors, but while dragging, press and hold both <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd>.
4. Release the mouse button before releasing <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd>.

### Transform palette

1. Select the object
2. Open the Transform Palette through Window > Transform
3. In the 9-dot diagram in the top left of the palette, click the centre dot—that's the reference point that stays in place
4. Click the 'chain' icon on the right so it shows the relation between height and width is 'locked'.
5. Enter a desired width or height, in absolute size or in precentage, in either the W or H fields and press enter.

When the Move or Free Transform tools are active, the Control bar also shows the options in the Transform palette.